# How to implement autocomplete in a modal using Jquery in MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a modal window where I want to display an Autocomplete of Jquery UI, this object is inside a form that will then be sent with a submit button to a controller action

[image: modal]

my modal window in my main view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="agregarProducto">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Agregar Material</h5>              
            </div>            
                <form id="myForm">
                    <label>Producto</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreproducto" id="nombreproducto" autofocus="" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Precio Producto</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="precio" id="idprecioproducto" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Agregar Material" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my Javascript code in my main view calls a JsonResult method that looks for a product:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#nombreproducto").autocomplete({
                source: "/Recepcions/BuscarProducto"
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

my controller:

```
public JsonResult BuscarProducto(string term)
{
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        var resultado = db.Productoes.Where(x => x.v_Nombre.Contains(term)).Select(y => y.v_Nombre).Take(10).ToList();
        return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

How can I establish that by pressing the button that calls my modal window

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#agregarProducto">Agregar Material </a>
```

Can my modal window be displayed with the autocomplete my products?

I have to call the event from my button? Where do I put the Jquery code? It's the first time that I have to develop something like that ... what Jquery events do I have to handle?

PS: this implementation goes to my controller's JsonResult, but obviously it's not displaying anything, why?

any example or help for me?

Comment: Are you saying the autocomplete does nothing currently? No reason it can't be made to work but not sure why it isn't already. Any errors in console? Are jQueryUI resources (js & css) included in page?

Comment: My Search Product method is executed, I do not like the suggestions of my products, what do I try to tell you? @charlietfl

Comment: What do you mean by *"I do not like the suggestions of my products"*? And what does the response json look like?

Comment: It's a mistake in my translation, I mean it does not show me anything, it does not show me @charlietfl

Comment: Ok so what is structure of the returned json?

Comment: What do you mean by structure? what the Json returns is a list with the products that contain the first letter that I enter @charlietfl

Comment: So it is an array of strings? Or array of objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171501/discussion-between-fytoahse-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using? If you are using these versions based on the documentation of [JQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), this might not work on your bootstrap modal due to conflicts.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Try to use these versions on your Javascript code and it works:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Here is the screenshot based on your code:

[image]